# Foreground Service dont run constantly

Tags: android, foreground-service

In my app I use a foreground service that must run constantly. Sometimes the foreground service is stopped.
Under what circumstances can the OS kill my service (it happen even if there is enough memory, battery is full, phone is charging)?

This is what my code looks like until now:

```
public class ServiceTest extends Service {

    public static Thread serverThread = null;
    public Context context = this;

    public ServiceTest(Context context) {
        super();
        this.context = context;
    }

    public ServiceTest() {

    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

        if (this.serverThread == null) {
            this.serverThread = new Thread(new ThreadTest());
            this.serverThread.start();
        }

        return START_STICKY;
    }

    private class ThreadTest implements Runnable {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
        notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);

        Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setContentTitle("Notification title")
                .setContentText("Notification text")
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
                .setAutoCancel(false)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.android)
                .setOngoing(true).build();

                startForeground(101, notification);

                while(true){
                    //work to do
                }
        }


    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

}
```

Comment: In which Android OS do you run? Is it Oreo?

Comment: Not on Oreo until now. Just from Android 4-7

Comment: how do you start this service?

Comment: on MainActivity, I check if the Service is started, if not I start it using: Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ServiceTest.getClass());
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_RECEIVER_FOREGROUND);
        if (!isMyServiceRunning(getApplicationContext(), ServiceTest.getClass())) {
            startService(intent);

        }

Comment: I also check if there is a BOOT_COMPLETED event using a BroadcastReceiver, and start the service from there using the same method

Comment: Dangerous implementation coding and implementation style.... though provided a answer....

Comment: thank you for your response. Im still new to android programming, I appreciate that you pointed where the problems were. Ill take a look again at android official documentation, and this time I`ll read it more carefully

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> There is not a single... `Many problems` in your code... You may be getting it "0 Errors" as it is syntactically correct but it is `androidicaly` wrong, your `basics` are poor, reading of `android documentation` and `implementation` is very poor. Android never runs very poor things...

### Problem : 1

Do you know for a service conventionally you should `override` `onCreate`, `onStartCommand`, `onBind`, `onDestroy` methods....?

> I don't see onDestroy there....!!

### Problem : 2

Do you know how to notify...? Your `onStartCommand` implementation is again making no sense.

> KEEP IT EMPTY JUST RETURN START_STICKY

### Problem : 3

How do you expect to run this under background execution limits...? Notify android first by making notification in `oncreate` only and with `startforeground` if needed...

> I don't see it there.... you trying to do it in `onstartcommand` and again it is very poorly...

Well... take a look at working code below :

```
public class RunnerService extends Service
{
NotificationManager mNotifyManager;
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder;
NotificationChannel notificationChannel;
String NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID = "1";

public RunnerService() { }

@Override
public void onCreate()
{
    super.onCreate();

    Log.d("RUNNER : ", "OnCreate... \n");

    Bitmap IconLg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground);

    mNotifyManager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, null);
    mBuilder.setContentTitle("My App")
            .setContentText("Always running...")
            .setTicker("Always running...")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_menu_slideshow)
            .setLargeIcon(IconLg)
            .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setVibrate(new long[] {1000})
            .setVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC)
            .setOngoing(true)
            .setAutoCancel(false);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    {
        notificationChannel = new NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID, "My Notifications", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);

        // Configure the notification channel.
        notificationChannel.setDescription("Channel description");
        notificationChannel.enableLights(true);
        notificationChannel.setLightColor(Color.RED);
        notificationChannel.setVibrationPattern(new long[]{1000});
        notificationChannel.enableVibration(true);
        notificationChannel.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PUBLIC);
        mNotifyManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);

        mBuilder.setChannelId(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
        startForeground(1, mBuilder.build());
    }
    else
    {
        mBuilder.setChannelId(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID);
        mNotifyManager.notify(1, mBuilder.build());
    }
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId)
{
    Log.d("RUNNER : ", "\nPERFORMING....");

    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy()
{
    Log.d("RUNNER : ", "\nDestroyed....");
    Log.d("RUNNER : ", "\nWill be created again automaticcaly....");
    super.onDestroy();
}


@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent)
{
    // TODO: Return the communication channel to the service.
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("NOT_YET_IMPLEMENTED");
}
}
```

### How to check....???

Remove the app from recents list and you should see in your logs the "`Performing` " message in `logcat`...

### In what conditions it stops...?

> It never stops ( until next boot..!! )... Yes it stops when user force stops application. And rarely if system finds it is having very low resources .... which is a very rare condition seems to occur as android has improved a lot over the time....

### How to start it....?????

Wherever it may be from `mainactivity` or from `receiver` or from any `class` :

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
        {
            context.startForegroundService(new Intent(context, RunnerService.class));

        }
        else
        {
            context.startService(new Intent(context, RunnerService.class));

        }
```

### How to check is service started or not....?

Simply Don't..... Even if you starts service how many times you wants.... If it is already running... then it won't be start again.... If not running then... will start it...!!

Comment: It is working very good. Thank you very much for your response.

Comment: What about if a service needs data from user(`intent`)? How to do it inside `onCreate()`.

Answer (score 2):

**The criticism made in the chosen answer is not reasonable if the service needs an intent to work.**

On higher version of Android, System will pause any foreground service while the device is locked, to minimize the power consumption ***even if it returns START_STICKY***. So, to make a foreground task constantly, a wakelock is required.

Here's what android documentation describes `wakeLock`:

> To avoid draining the battery, an Android device that is left idle quickly falls asleep. However, there are times when an application needs to wake up the screen or the CPU and keep it awake to complete some work.

To make a foreground service running constantly, acquire a `wakeLock` from inside the `onCreate()`.

```java
PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
WakeLock wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,
        "MyApp::MyWakelockTag");
wakeLock.acquire();
```

For further detail, have a look at [official Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock#java).

Comment: This infomation really helped to solve the problem that foregroundService often gets delayed on latest androids such as 12 & 13. Thanks a lot!