# Oreo background service limits START_STICKY problem

Tags: android, service, android-8.0-oreo, foreground-service

After android oreo  , there is some limitations about service usage .I could not understand how limits affect code? For example, İf I start service by startService function and return Start_STICKY in startcommand function ,service will be restart after kill.I could not see any problem here about android 8.I could listen location updated in background service .What is the limitations here? Returning start_sticky is enough to recreate and . run service again?

Comment: Service will not run in background so you surly can not listen to location updates in background . That's not all Doze and app standby mode will also affect the location updates . You should check out the background restrictions doc .

Answer (score 0):

i was researching on this topic from last 3 days.finally i read about android 8 background service limit from android developer website and only one thing is important if you want to run your service in background then you should show notification in your app within 5 second  otherwise you will get illegal Exception
Here is implementation

```
  @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        startInForeground();
    }

 private void startInForeground() {
        Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, SplashScreenActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent=PendingIntent.getActivity(this,0,notificationIntent,0);
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this,"some_channel_id")
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_motion_new)
                .setContentTitle("Sure")
                .setContentText("Local call notification")
                .setTicker("TICKER")
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        Notification notification=builder.build();
        NotificationChannel channel = null;
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            channel = new NotificationChannel("local_call_notification", "Local Call", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MIN);
            channel.setDescription("Local Call Notification");
            NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);

        }
        startForeground(2, notification);

        NotificationManager notificationManager= (NotificationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.cancel(2);
    }
```

Start service

Intent startServiceIntent = new Intent(context, xyz.class);

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    context.startForegroundService(startServiceIntent);
} else {
    context.startService(startServiceIntent);
}
```

Comment: I know this rules also I can start service with context.startService(startServiceIntent);  (oreo or later) when app is on foreground. I could not see any problem now about limitations.START_STICKY will start service again after kill.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51823543/foreground-service-dont-run-constantly

Answer (score 0):

According to my test, when *service* was running in the background, if manually killed the application, service would restarted by setting *start_sticky*. but when the service runs in the background for a period of time, the system will automatically kill the service, regardless of whether Start_Sticky parameter has be setted. Another phenomenon is that when I run on Android 10, no matter how I set the parameter, the service will not be automatically restarted.

Answer (score 0):

On higher version of Android, System will pause any foreground service while the device is locked, to minimize the power consumption ***even if it returns START_STICKY***. So, to make a foreground task constantly, a wakelock is required.

Here's what android documentation describes `wakeLock`:

> To avoid draining the battery, an Android device that is left idle quickly falls asleep. However, there are times when an application needs to wake up the screen or the CPU and keep it awake to complete some work.

To make a foreground service running constantly, acquire a `wakeLock` from inside the `onCreate()`.

```java
PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) getSystemService(POWER_SERVICE);
WakeLock wakeLock = powerManager.newWakeLock(PowerManager.PARTIAL_WAKE_LOCK,
        "MyApp::MyWakelockTag");
wakeLock.acquire();
```

For further detail, have a look at [official Android Documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock#java).